# Edit message in socket.io before it is sent to the user

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'd like to intercept certain messages being sent **in the receiver point of view**. This means, for example:

### SENDER SIDE

1. User sends message
2. Server receives message
3. Message could be treated here **but I don't want to work it here**

### RECEIVER SIDE

1. **I want to treat it in the server before being emit**
2. Message is emit
3. User receives message (for example, in browser) with ***socket.on('message',(...));***

Does anyone have any idea which part of the code needs to be changed in socket.io to accomplish that? I've been searching the modules: adapter, client, parser... but found nothing relevant... Any thoughts on this one? I've been getting a bit desperate xp

Comment: You can monkey patch `socket.on()` so you see every `.on()` call and thus see every incoming message before the actual handler.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought that too but still I had problems trying to find the code block. I will try again and I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

server side:

```
socket.on("chat", clientMsg);

function clientMsg(data){
  console.log("data received:" + data)
  var msg = data; // set the msg to be sent
  // treat the data server side or
  // if wanting to treat the data from the user's side 
  // create another socket.on() inside this function. to treat it remotely (if needed)
  
  // then, when finished send the message to all users with the treated data.
  io.sockets.emit("chat", msg)

};
```